# Could not load type custom from assembly custom SharePoint 2007

Tags: 2007

Recently I tried to add a aspx page by copying existing page and rename it with desired name. I was able to successfully deploy it but now the original page from which I copied is not rendering it is throwing error

> An error occurred during the processing of . Could not load type
>   'MyCustomSolution.Portals.Name.CourseDetails' from assembly
>   'MyCustomSolution.Portals.Name, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=9f4da00116c38ec5'.

This is only with CourseDetails Page. Rest All pages are working fine without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new page with another name and removed old page from module.xml . This has resolved my problem.